# postgresql: hindi encode and decode error

Tags: postgresql

```
select encode('नमस्त', 'base64');

        encode        
──────────────────────
 4KSo4KSu4KS44KWN4KSk


select decode('4KSo4KSu4KS44KWN4KSk','base64');

              decode              
──────────────────────────────────
 \xe0a4a8e0a4aee0a4b8e0a58de0a4a4
```

Why does not this return the Hindi text?

collate: en_US.UTF-8
Ctype: en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation tells you what exactly `decode()` returns:

> ```
> Function                          Return Type   Description
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> decode(string text, format text)  bytea         Decode binary data from textual 
>                                                 representation in string.
> ```

`'\xe0a4a8e0a4aee0a4b8e0a58de0a4a4'` is the `bytea` output.  You need an additional call of `convert_from()` to turn this back to text:

```
SELECT convert_from(decode(encode('नमस्त', 'base64'), 'base64'), 'utf8');
 convert_from 
──────────────
 नमस्त
```